# phrase for the intersection of two ranges?

Tags: terminology

This question is more about the language used by mathematicians. The intersection of the ranges $A=[0,2]$ and $B = [1,3]$ is $C=[1,2]$. Now, which sentences are correct?

1. $C$ is the intersecting range of $A$ and $B$.
2. $C$ is the overlapping range of $A$ and $B$.
3. $C$ is the overlapped range of $A$ and $B$.
4. $C$ is the intersection range of $A$ and $B$.

I'm looking for a phrase where the word "range" is modified by another word.

Comment: Or "of the ranges of ..."

Comment: Does it have to contain “range”? Because “$C$ is the intersection of $A$ and $B$” is perfectly valid, and that $C$ here must be a range is usually wide-known.

Comment: @SahibaArora, The problem is I'm supposed not to use symbols. Assume we have two ranges of time, each defined by a description (e.g. "the range of time between the extinction of dinosaurs and the advent of humans"). These two ranges are defined previously in the text. Now, I should speak about their intersection. I'm looking for a short phrase, like "the overlapping range of time", "the intersecting range of temperatures", etc.